# Changing the color of a section of text within a li

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a dropdown menu which at at the minute has a different coloured title above different sections in the menu e.g

Title (colour1)

option1 (colour2)

option2 (colour2)

option3 (colour2)

I would like to change it so that on the list it looks is as follows (two colours on one line):

Title (colour1) Option1 (colour 2)

Title (colour1) Option2 (colour 2)

Title (colour1) Option3 (colour 2)

Could someone help me with the code please? the html is as follows:

```
                   <div id="dropbox"></div>
                    <div id="Dropp style="position:relative;z-index:1000">
<div id="drop" style="position:absolute;z-index:3000">
    <ul>
        <li id="dropbox"><span class="nav-title" style="z-index:3000">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011</span> <div class="nav-title" id="triangle">
                    </div>
            <ul id="ddd" class="subnav" style:"display: none;" >
                <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <li>—</li>
            <li class="section-title">
                <span class="section-title">Photographers Gallery</span>
            </li>
                <li><a href="Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011.html">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2011</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Deutsche Börse Photography Prize 2010</a></li>
```

And the css:

```
#drop {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:inherit;
    left: 183px;
    width:700px;
    top: 15px;
    }

#drop ul {
    background: #fff;
    list-style-type: none;      
    }

#drop ul li {
    width: 750px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;      
    margin: 0 10px -10 0;
    }

#drop ul li span {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;      
    padding: 1px 3px;
    }

#drop ul li ul {
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    list-style-type: none;      
    display: none; 
    padding: 0 0em 0.5em 0;
    }

#drop ul li:hover ul {
    list-style-type: none;      
    opacity: 0.9;
    }

#drop ul li ul li {
    border: none;       
    list-style-type: none;  
    float: none;
    padding-left:0px;
    }

#drop ul li ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #808285;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    }


#drop ul li ul li a:hover {
    background: #d8d8dc;
    }


#drop ul li.section-title SPAN.section-title {
    color:#434442;
    margin-left: -3px;
    }

span.nav-title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #808285;   
    position:fixed;
    left: 223px;
    width:744px;
    top: 28px;
    cursor:pointer;

    }
```

Comment: A link to a demo would be nice, especially considering the HTML you've provided is incomplete and invalid.

Comment: Sorry its http://deanpauley.co.uk/O-SB/categories.html

Comment: @Chris  deanpauley.co.uk/O-SB/categories.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
    <li class="section"><span class="title">Title 1</span><span class="content">Color 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

and then do you want 2 background colors? or text colors?

```
li.section {
    padding: 0;
}

li.section span.title {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #COLOR1;
}

li.section span.content {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #COLOR2;
}
```

The padding and margin are there to make two parts fit together nicely (if you are talking about background-color.

i.e.

```
-----------
|    |    |
-----------
```

not

```
------  ------
|    |  |    |
------  ------
```

Comment: Anyone know how I can get the two colors on the one line?

Comment: My Example Came out just fine. Make sure your padding and margin settings aren't pushing the second one down. What browser are you using? Have you tested others? Also, you should update your code. There are a few mistakes (i.e. style:"display:none" should be style="display:none" you are missing some tags, and the <br>'s should be <br />(

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure. Still can't figure it out. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Tried it on 3 different browsers. Think the padding and margin settings are ok: